# Looping through records with SQL server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Being an MS Access bod, our IT group doesn't let me touch the SQL server much so I don't know how to do looping of recordsets in it for a scheduled job I need.  I have pseudo-coded what I want to do but would be very grateful if someone could point out how this is done...

```
for every record in qry_deliveryqueue
loop
if not fail then
  send docID field to SP_sendfile
  set delivereddate=getdate()
else
 insert into tbl_errors (errdate,docid) values (getdate(), docid)
endif
next record
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to loop though an SQL Server record set in MS Access? If so, do you have linked tables?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're after is a `CURSOR`. The documentation has good examples that should point you in the right direction. You probably want to write a stored procedure around the logic and call that from the scheduler.

Cursors are generally inefficient, but I am assuming that your sp_sendfile has some more complex logic that precludes treating all the records as a set

Answer (score 0):

You can [Sql while syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx) or [Sql Cursor Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ion SQL server(This code is sample of while loop.So you have to tweak it as per your requirements)

--In sql server

```
Declare @idmin int,@idmax int
select @idmin=MIN(id) from  qry_deliveryqueue --This is first record in qry_deliveryqueue
select @idmax=MAX(id) from  qry_deliveryqueue --This is last record in qry_deliveryqueue
--You can 
While(@idmin <= @idmax)
begin
IF @flag<>'Fail'
begin
--  send docID field to SP_sendfile
--  set delivereddate=getdate()
end
else
begin
insert into tbl_errors (errdate,docid) values (getdate(), docid)
end
SET @idmin=@idmin+1
end
```